# Adding Nodes to a list. At the moment I cannot add the second node.

Tags: java, linked-list, custom-lists

```
public void addNode(Car newCarEntry){
    ListNode currentNode;
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newCarEntry);

    if (head == null || newCarEntry.isNewerThan(head.carItem)){
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        currentNode = head.next;
        while(currentNode != null && !newCarEntry.isNewerThan(currentNode.carItem) ){
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        currentNode.next = newNode.next;
        currentNode = newNode;
    }
    numberOfNodes++;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to use a more sensible title and give a clearer description. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more suggestions.

Comment: What do you see when you attempt to debug your program?

Comment: `newNode.next = currentNode;  newNode = currentNode;`<< it doesn't make sense

Comment: I normally see that the first node is added twice, instead of the second node being added at all.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like homework, so I'm not going to be putting any code in here, but in your else statement you are finding the insertion point for the new node, and setting the new node's next to point to the remainder of the list, but you are not actually putting your new node in the list at any point.

Comment: This is for an inventory program. The list adds cars to a swing table. Not for homework, my CS classes haven't thought me how to design linked lists yet, I'm a first year CS student. Thus my problem with pointers and my inability to properly implement a linked list. that's why i came to stackoverflow... hopefully I can get a quick tutorial on how to add nodes to this list by abstracting the adding of the nodes after the first node by using a else statement clause

Comment: why are you writing your own linked list if this isn't for homework? [java.util.LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Comment: I need to sort the nodes using multiple attributes, car mileage, make and model

Comment: perhaps you could look at the http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html or http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html interfaces so you can use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)  Honestly, I would suggest basically anything besides writing your own list class.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a one-node list `[HEAD]->null`. Now the following lines will be executed:

```
currentNode = head.next; // => null
while(currentNode.next != null && !newCarEntry.isNewerThan(currentNode.carItem) ){
    ...
}
```

Thus it will give you a null pointer exception (accessing `currentNode.next`) when you try to add the second node.

**After the Edit**: Now the null pointer exception will not come up any more. Instead the following happens:

```
currentNode = head.next;              // => null
while(currentNode != null && ...) {   // => not entering loop
    ...
}
newNode.next = currentNode;           // => i.e. null
newNode = currentNode;                // => i.e. null
```

You are only changing the local variable `newNode` but not the list or the head at all.

Comment: Right then it should skip the while loop and add the node.

Comment: K I edited it so it will instead add the pointer from newNode to currentNode which is pointing to the list.